# LWJGL: Text line-break

Tags: java, opengl, text, lwjgl, drawstring

In legacy LWJGL when you use `(TrueTypeFont).drawString(xPos, yPos, "the text");`, I now wonder if you can use line-breaks in the text(like: \n), or you will have to do one function call per row?

Comment: Did you try it to find out?

Comment: It didnt work by using \n